# Tab not loading the content onclick and opening only on double click

Tags: c#, jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

Am having a tab as below

```
     <div id="tabs" style="width:1060px">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#OverviewDiv">Overview</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowDetails()">General Info</a></li>                  
     <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowDetails()">Dimension</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowDetails()">Blocking</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="ShowDetails()">History</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
```

and the onclick method as below:

```
          function ShowDetails() {                                                              
                            //    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", i);                              

                            var AccNum = $("#SelId").val();

                            if (AccNum != null && AccNum != "") {
                       var url = '/InventJournalGeneral/Details/' + AccNum;

                                window.open(url, "_self");

                            }
                            else {
                                alert('Choose any one Journal Id');
                            }

                        }
```

Only on double click of the tab am able to see the tab loaded and not on the single click.  Also I suppose the tab which i click is not selected and it is always on the tab 0 .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<li class="click">General Info</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on('click', function (evt) {
        if($(evt.target).hasClass('click')){
            alert("hello");
        } 
    });
});
```

Comment: No. This doesnt work. Also I need to set the clicked tab to active or selected.

Comment: Well, you can change the style of the clicked element in the jquery function: $(this).text('changed text').css('background', 'yellow');

Comment: I want the  tab to selected on single click of the respective tab and load the contents.   Now it is loading the page only on double click of the tab. Also the selected tab remains to be the first tab.